# How to fix Django logger Permission denied in Docker container?

Tags: django, docker

I'm trying to run my Django project on docker
I'm using logger to write in a .txt file but I'm getting an error related to permissions
Django can't write in AdminFileDebug.txt
This is the settings.py code

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'handlers': {
    'adminsDebug': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': 'log/AdminFileDebug.txt',
        'formatter': 'verbose'
        # 'filename': '/path/to/django/debug.log',
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'AdminsDebug': {
        'handlers': ['adminsDebug', 'console'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
},
'formatters': {
    'verbose': {
        'format': '{levelname} {asctime} {module} {process:d} {thread:d} {message}',
        'style': '{',
    },
    'simple': {
        'format': '{levelname} {asctime} {message}',
        'style': '{',
    },
},
```

}

This is the docker compose file for my configuration:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres

    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=test
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test

 app:
   build:
   context: .
   command: sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
   volumes:
     - .:/app
   ports:
     - 8000:8000
   environment:
    - DJANGO_DEBUG=1
    - POSTGRES_NAME=test
    - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test
   depends_on:
    - db
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10-alpine3.16

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN apk add --upgrade --no-cache build-base linux-headers && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install -r /requirements.txt

 COPY app/ /app
 WORKDIR /app

 RUN adduser --disabled-password --no-create-home django

 USER django

 CMD ["uwsgi", "--socket", ":9000", "--workers", "4", "--master", "--enable-threads", "--module", "app.wsgi"]
```

when i run docker compose up i get this error

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/app/log/AdminFileDebug.txt'
```

Any solutions?

Comment: What user is running your Django app? What user owns the file `/app/log/AdminFileDebug.txt` and its parent directories?

Comment: I'm running this on the server. how do i know the user?
I only know the server username 'test43'

Comment: The beauty of docker is that you can run it locally and have the exact same environment as on the server. Start with `docker compose up`. Then get a shell in the docker container with `docker compose exec app /bin/bash`. Finally use commands to find what you need, such as `whoami`, `cd` and `ls -l` as appropriate.

Comment: On a side note, you should use a real web server, such as nginx or apache, when running these docker containers on a public server. The django server you get with `python manage.py runserver` isn't appropriate for production. It won't handle very many users and it isn't secure.

Comment: Is there any links that explains how to convert to production?

Comment: Also still can't solve that permission problem

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in my comment about how to figure out the permission problem?

Comment: yes when typing 'docker compose exec app /bin/bash' it shows this 'WARN[0000] The "h" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. ' and then this error 'OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/bin/bash": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory: unknown'

Comment: The easiest way to set this up in Docker is to set your containers to log to stdout; `docker logs` can retrieve this later, and standard log-management systems know how to retrieve the container logs as well.  This also avoids the permission you describe.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the `Dockerfile` used to build your docker image. I recently saw a similar error in my own project. It was because the `entrypoint.sh` which I used for the `ENTRYPOINT` in my Dockerfile wasn't set with executable permissions.

Comment: I just added dockerfile configuration

Comment: @David Maze how am i supposed to do that?

Comment: You should be able to use `'class': 'logging.StreamHandler'` in your configuration, and remove the `filename` option.